# What does "factoring" mean in the context of ring epimorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, epimorphisms

Let $f\colon A \to B$, $g\colon A \to C$ be two ring epimorphisms. What does it mean when one says that these two factor into another ring epimorphism $h\colon B \to C$? I'm guessing that it means that this $h$ is the unique epimorphism such that $g = h\circ f$, but I'm not sure and I haven't found any definition for this concept.

Comment: It just means that $h$ is an epimorphism such that $g=h\circ f$. If one want to add the uniqueness, then one adds the word *unique*.